# Simplest LINQ in C# troubleshooting

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to learn a bit of LINQ but I'm having compile issues right off the bat. Is there any specific reason why this won't work?

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Text;  


namespace HelloLINQ {

    class HelloLINQ
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Example1();
        }


        public static void Example1()
        {
            var numbers = new int[] { 1, 5, 3, 7, 3, 8, 9, 3, 6, 6, 2 };
            var under5 = from n in numbers
                         select n;
            foreach (var n in under5)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(n);
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

The error is:

> Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'int[]'. 'Select' not found. Are you missing a reference to 'System.Core.dll' or a using directive for 'System.Linq'?

Comment: Have you tried this with List<Int> rather than int[]?

Comment: The error is clear. Are you missing a reference to the correct version of System.Core.dll? It should work if that's not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, we have an error message, carefully written by a Microsoft employee to be helpful, so let's look at it.
`Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'int[]'. 'Select' not found. Are you missing a reference to 'System.Core.dll' or a using directive for 'System.Linq'?`
`int[]` is a basic C# type. Where are the basic C# types located? System.Core. And the error mentions checking for a reference to System.Core. So, is there a reference to System.Core?
To check this:
Solution Explorer->References. In the list, do you see System.Core?
If not, weird, but it's easily addable. Right click on references, look under .NET for System.Core, add it, and voila.

Comment: `int[]` is not located in `System.Core`. The LINQ extension methods are.

Comment: care to share where is it located then?

Comment: @Matti: Isn't System.Core the CLR base? Or was that mscorlib?

Comment: System.Array is in mscorlib.dll  This message is looking for Enumerable.Select is in System.Core.dll... or something like Enumerable.Select that works specifically for arrays *spooky music*

Comment: i resolved this issue adding reference for System.Linq

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a reference to System.Core in your project?  Everything else is correct.